# iphone app crash, crash log posted

Tags: iphone, crash

we recenty had a programmer to develop a program for us but seems to have left us in the lurch with a part functioning application. my boss isnt happy  at moment as we have spent a few hundred and have nothing to show for it at the moment.

can anyone see any information in the crash log below as its gibberish to me.

```
    Incident Identifier: D4F482FE-167A-44BB-A642-7E8EF7B568BF
CrashReporter Key:   2d8e2d17415c55e48ec20dae7cbe6c36b33bcce1
Process:         Logistics [328]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/32A03443-ADE3-4AAE-AB32-05DB7BEB15D8/Logistics.app/Logistics
Identifier:      Logistics
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-03-29 17:07:06.474 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31a279ac 0x319a9000 + 518572
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31a2799c 0x319a9000 + 518556
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31a2798e 0x319a9000 + 518542
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31a3c63a 0x319a9000 + 603706
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x3361d3b0 0x335d8000 + 283568
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32401858 0x323fc000 + 22616
6   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x3361b776 0x335d8000 + 276342
7   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x3361b7ca 0x335d8000 + 276426
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x3361b896 0x335d8000 + 276630
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32400714 0x323fc000 + 18196
10  CoreFoundation                 0x32537b86 0x32511000 + 158598
11  CoreFoundation                 0x32537b24 0x32511000 + 158500
12  Foundation                     0x3145ddaa 0x313ed000 + 462250
13  Foundation                     0x31454ee2 0x313ed000 + 425698
14  Logistics                      0x00002df8 0x1000 + 7672
15  CoreFoundation                 0x32569ede 0x32511000 + 364254
16  UIKit                          0x32ba205e 0x32b60000 + 270430
17  UIKit                          0x32bf4d4e 0x32b60000 + 609614
18  CoreFoundation                 0x32569ede 0x32511000 + 364254
19  UIKit                          0x32ba205e 0x32b60000 + 270430
20  UIKit                          0x32ba1ffe 0x32b60000 + 270334
21  UIKit                          0x32ba1fd0 0x32b60000 + 270288
22  UIKit                          0x32ba1d2a 0x32b60000 + 269610
23  UIKit                          0x32ba263e 0x32b60000 + 271934
24  UIKit                          0x32ba1656 0x32b60000 + 267862
25  UIKit                          0x32ba1032 0x32b60000 + 266290
26  UIKit                          0x32b9d928 0x32b60000 + 252200
27  UIKit                          0x32b9d3a0 0x32b60000 + 250784
28  GraphicsServices               0x32913b72 0x3290f000 + 19314
29  CoreFoundation                 0x32567c26 0x32511000 + 355366
30  CoreFoundation                 0x32567356 0x32511000 + 353110
31  GraphicsServices               0x32912cb8 0x3290f000 + 15544
32  GraphicsServices               0x32912d64 0x3290f000 + 15716
33  UIKit                          0x32b62768 0x32b60000 + 10088
34  UIKit                          0x32b6146c 0x32b60000 + 5228
35  Logistics                      0x000023c4 0x1000 + 5060
36  Logistics                      0x00002380 0x1000 + 4992

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319a9818 0x319a9000 + 2072
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319abff8 0x319a9000 + 12280
2   CoreFoundation                 0x325677f6 0x32511000 + 354294
3   CoreFoundation                 0x32567356 0x32511000 + 353110
4   WebCore                        0x305d59de 0x30578000 + 383454
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319cd92a 0x319a9000 + 149802

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31a28228 0x319a9000 + 520744
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319d3244 0x319a9000 + 172612
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319d2d0e 0x319a9000 + 171278
3   CoreMedia                      0x33552b04 0x3354f000 + 15108
4   CoreMedia                      0x33552a3a 0x3354f000 + 14906
5   MediaToolbox                   0x31e1b50c 0x31e18000 + 13580
6   libSystem.B.dylib              0x319cd92a 0x319a9000 + 149802

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x383c43cc
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3361b30d      r6: 0x00172f5c      r7: 0x2fffe97c
    r8: 0x2fffe968    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00007150     r11: 0x334bd104
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffe97c      lr: 0x31a279a3      pc: 0x31a279ac
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x6fff +Logistics armv6  <350fc970d77b4d8d67bf43f4d7f2a68c> /var/mobile/Applications/32A03443-ADE3-4AAE-AB32-05DB7BEB15D8/Logistics.app/Logistics
   0x2c000 -    0x2dfff  dns.so armv7  <35ac487c38e38ed5810d5ed0d5c67546> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe24fff  dyld armv7  <5db9f5d0275997de58efff111816706e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30028000 - 0x3004ffff  ContentIndex armv7  <67165d749b79ad4b14c8a24f14dab29d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x30050000 - 0x30054fff  ITSync armv7  <a0bf9af6f4ebc7e5977d3da853671162> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30149000 - 0x3016efff  AppSupport armv7  <ca2e9a4f0475af20028968840ab94ecf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30175000 - 0x3017ffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <36d71cd8dd49f5d5addb356f449b562a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30184000 - 0x30184fff  Accelerate armv7  <939f94df6c7e6e7a090ddee1ec09c844> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30185000 - 0x301b7fff  iCalendar armv7  <235e05f7e167e6dbbd75528a4a37f3a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x301b8000 - 0x301c3fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8faba7ded9b3527ccf54c2f224f9a12f> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x301c4000 - 0x301eefff  CoreText armv7  <821e9c7c935b6a8d735e2d2d9ebcee04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x301f6000 - 0x301fffff  IAP armv7  <36e57cf20df9fcea10ebd0d1c3526a9a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30247000 - 0x30279fff  MessageUI armv7  <51d0498fb3dba758dae660754f1afb9c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3027a000 - 0x3027efff  MobileMusicPlayer armv7  <f0e7d2d2d69e9cc2a84e20bced0e1d07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileMusicPlayer.framework/MobileMusicPlayer
0x302c6000 - 0x302cefff  CoreVideo armv7  <9259f5ae2a74b53e4f13b27fa3d511e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30348000 - 0x3034afff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <a0a25c381e45f8a3f4ec63bcb17a5a39> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x304a3000 - 0x304cefff  MIME armv7  <55a4de1d243273ee7ef4e86a85d591f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x304cf000 - 0x3050ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <c2b5985d8307d73b39140e76adfd2eb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3054a000 - 0x30569fff  Bom armv7  <37e498957087af50894156808e0a486b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30578000 - 0x30a4efff  WebCore armv7  <4e2bac4e01a15979c9ac096f78280db0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30a58000 - 0x30b12fff  Message armv7  <a5a7de97c57a6965f27547bf8ff8810c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x30b13000 - 0x30b13fff  vecLib armv7  <4eb91bf56603dc0db6784d8d3240bfa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30c1e000 - 0x30c23fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <91af9ee5b2f271cbd8c138b3c61e508d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30d05000 - 0x30d29fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <c57df668b510f025ee5a173ad30fb48e> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30d6c000 - 0x30decfff  QuartzCore armv7  <af0722911ffc74fc08075e9831a6222e> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30e5d000 - 0x30e72fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2b6a9404652dd2b5abd1c6a5583e8533> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30e73000 - 0x30ebdfff  GMM armv7  <72c87b3b08ab4359802b6efed472bf46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x30ec7000 - 0x30ed0fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <17ca8b5262cd6484d41efdc72c6fd057> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30ed1000 - 0x30f43fff  LDAP armv7  <a5f6d51ebcab28eeabe0f2bbbdeb8cc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LDAP.framework/LDAP
0x30fe6000 - 0x30ffbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <be80a5e4c55c2920be2c31f740bb9dba> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31003000 - 0x31009fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <04ab19af95239c12a98539478eebc560> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x3114f000 - 0x311acfff  MediaPlayer armv7  <1021fc5da1419ba297464f71049ad084> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x311ad000 - 0x311cefff  CoreLocation armv7  <a3857b8324f90ae48994df15fdfbcda6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x311d5000 - 0x31214fff  Celestial armv7  <f8bde8e040e6aac9e36e0aa8b43ee8cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x312f6000 - 0x312fcfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <263b2691cd12171b31fa600716104e4a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x31338000 - 0x31367fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <2ec5ad6812f5ea3859cb4189d62b7265> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31393000 - 0x313cafff  IOKit armv7  <0afabe8bf08fc163ba8e4ed614092cd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x313e9000 - 0x313eafff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <9d9f0254b5b64ced3d58191748f3027b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x313ed000 - 0x314e2fff  Foundation armv7  <ede5b943f529ce1b862c15dc876992c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x314ed000 - 0x31599fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <a491bfc5f062f33185a3f98969bae3c2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x315fc000 - 0x315fefff  MobileInstallation armv7  <b8ebf64838bdfe5315dab5745482e30c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31919000 - 0x31923fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <bc6cf9563c3a14a86cde6ddf6cc3ed45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x31926000 - 0x319a8fff  WebKit armv7  <b9b7246a09f5db68e44497d318cb3ab6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x319a9000 - 0x31aa0fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <3f94d4b13815a93cbdfc6c7dc2afe5b4> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31aa2000 - 0x31b8bfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <393fa1e155bb0523c2a90555bb394498> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x31b8d000 - 0x31bfcfff  CFNetwork armv7  <b55671f2472fdae3f811ae6f636b4e2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31cb2000 - 0x31d12fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <5e5b83d3c9e2c0676671feebfb8d37c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31d19000 - 0x31d21fff  AccountSettings armv7  <37a8916d02c399bfccc56e92ad68e84b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31d28000 - 0x31d34fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <d757be3521f8ed71709728790c29bdb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x31d3a000 - 0x31d3cfff  Notes armv7  <f7c579348cb58b5f2218c042cf46f422> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31d59000 - 0x31d5cfff  IOSurface armv7  <81661b8e151a9af6ce5704a728e12dc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31e18000 - 0x31ed8fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <b9023dc22073ab28f6fb8ecbe00951c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31ed9000 - 0x31f8dfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <d3434c868a9a0f4016ed32ba90a35c4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31f91000 - 0x320e6fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <5852bd39fd1ef304da7b017949755cab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32150000 - 0x3217cfff  DAVKit armv7  <80cf41b34d377d21d406fcb6835fbf77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAVKit.framework/DAVKit
0x321d4000 - 0x322d5fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1081389fef915d9b8858d0dfff04568e> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x322d6000 - 0x322d9fff  ActorKit armv7  <c81b8278a35c6e8293aaf7c55811ba2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x322da000 - 0x32388fff  DataAccess armv7  <e9225a8b94fe76047095ebecd6fd58c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x32389000 - 0x32390fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <6675987a84fc3d127305c175085914aa> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x323fc000 - 0x32499fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <1a57ecb9f5c0f274a274b3eb53df48ed> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x324b5000 - 0x324cbfff  AddressBook armv7  <c21d7ab21d7e67f84c487bc278568bbe> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x324d6000 - 0x32510fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <5b68ed8ffac45237acc948e9d5bb5e83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32511000 - 0x325bbfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <51c03f1f8755868781e3e719d8df7b6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x325ca000 - 0x3268bfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <ce4922bef1cc1d6706da32480c2272bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3268c000 - 0x3268efff  AppleJPEG armv7  <af51b716dce446178b366a8d5af48ebb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x3268f000 - 0x326adfff  MobileSync armv7  <1eecaede37e5d042180473311efccda3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x32860000 - 0x3286bfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <73c2bec8b5f870ea528f359c2374f19c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3286c000 - 0x328f2fff  ImageIO armv7  <ea76d0fd3ca8c1a6104bc0f013255e2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3290f000 - 0x32918fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <5387c7197570ac7df97759c0402d453d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32933000 - 0x3299bfff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <0535fc553452b7b6cc25ac990cff4a40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x3299f000 - 0x329ccfff  Calendar armv7  <52446b9087d707210cb515b0894afee5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Calendar.framework/Calendar
0x329d6000 - 0x329fffff  TextInput armv7  <2e983bf3876bfeaf7151aa8a0e68dabc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x32a01000 - 0x32a02fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f3aae0195e4510657029b19161138593> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32a09000 - 0x32a0bfff  Camera armv7  <81c49c0f094225be8a6ad129a8641c86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera
0x32a56000 - 0x32a7efff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d846b621ce13b16241ac2d32ddd28615> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32a81000 - 0x32a86fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5b665cd59d9884ceecec6441fc42bc14> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32a8a000 - 0x32a96fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <ad1aeb0c6df9b0b917c1c99405e36cc4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32ab5000 - 0x32ac3fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <b34206a34dfb1cc4183274cc6c0a3f36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x32ac4000 - 0x32ae5fff  MobileQuickLook armv7  <06cb03b3f1bd2c5bfa27ba2aef0849b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x32aed000 - 0x32b07fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <0dc4e83b63c1350517949e24204817fb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32b09000 - 0x32b2dfff  Security armv7  <3a3406fe12445942f4d767c7fa4c24ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32b2e000 - 0x32b5bfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <08b68b92f987faff46a127f6f78708a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32b60000 - 0x33524fff  UIKit armv7  <47c9d61f9cbe72938d1bfb1588306b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3354f000 - 0x33580fff  CoreMedia armv7  <584770f5de9c599a2d420eb8666921ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33586000 - 0x33588fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <66057eb40ba62cb544fe00ac4f2b498e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x33594000 - 0x33599fff  MBX2D armv7  <ae091892e4419221d25f8db9307cedf0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3359a000 - 0x335d7fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1eb427066a911d979a024e445464a067> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x335d8000 - 0x33621fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <99401ed10ec4d5608ce23ec33dd757c6> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33627000 - 0x33632fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <03f3879bad1802636dadeb457ee74cb2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
```

**EDIT:**

ok here goes

```
Incident Identifier: 100F6562-5881-4848-B170-39853565B275
CrashReporter Key:   2d8e2d17415c55e48ec20dae7cbe6c36b33bcce1
Process:         Logistics [952]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E10C8ED3-1B10-4D06-A711-5562BAF2DE7A/Logistics.app/Logistics
Identifier:      Logistics
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-04-08 15:09:16.012 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31a279ac 0x319a9000 + 518572
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31a2799c 0x319a9000 + 518556
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31a2798e 0x319a9000 + 518542
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31a3c63a 0x319a9000 + 603706
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3361d3b0 0x335d8000 + 283568
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32401858 0x323fc000 + 22616
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3361b776 0x335d8000 + 276342
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3361b7ca 0x335d8000 + 276426
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3361b896 0x335d8000 + 276630
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32400714 0x323fc000 + 18196
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32537b86 0x32511000 + 158598
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32537b24 0x32511000 + 158500
12  Foundation                      0x3145ddaa 0x313ed000 + 462250
13  Foundation                      0x31454ee2 0x313ed000 + 425698
14  Logistics                       0x00003904 -[RootViewController sendMessage:] (RootViewController.m:139)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x32569ede 0x32511000 + 364254
16  UIKit                           0x32ba205e 0x32b60000 + 270430
17  UIKit                           0x32bf4d4e 0x32b60000 + 609614
18  CoreFoundation                  0x32569ede 0x32511000 + 364254
19  UIKit                           0x32c4a060 0x32b60000 + 958560
20  UIKit                           0x32c66500 0x32b60000 + 1074432
21  UIKit                           0x32c153f0 0x32b60000 + 742384
22  UIKit                           0x32c66e00 0x32b60000 + 1076736
23  UIKit                           0x32c5403c 0x32b60000 + 999484
24  UIKit                           0x32c50450 0x32b60000 + 984144
25  UIKit                           0x32c4ffa2 0x32b60000 + 982946
26  UIKit                           0x32b9ec1a 0x32b60000 + 257050
27  UIKit                           0x32b9d84a 0x32b60000 + 251978
28  UIKit                           0x32b9d3a0 0x32b60000 + 250784
29  GraphicsServices                0x32913b72 0x3290f000 + 19314
30  CoreFoundation                  0x32567c26 0x32511000 + 355366
31  CoreFoundation                  0x32567356 0x32511000 + 353110
32  GraphicsServices                0x32912cb8 0x3290f000 + 15544
33  GraphicsServices                0x32912d64 0x3290f000 + 15716
34  UIKit                           0x32b62768 0x32b60000 + 10088
35  UIKit                           0x32b6146c 0x32b60000 + 5228
36  Logistics                       0x00002d3a main (main.m:11)
37  Logistics                       0x00002cd0 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319a9818 0x319a9000 + 2072
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319abff8 0x319a9000 + 12280
2   CoreFoundation                  0x325677f6 0x32511000 + 354294
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32567356 0x32511000 + 353110
4   WebCore                         0x305d59de 0x30578000 + 383454
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319cd92a 0x319a9000 + 149802

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31a28228 0x319a9000 + 520744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319d3244 0x319a9000 + 172612
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319d2d0e 0x319a9000 + 171278
3   CoreMedia                       0x33552b04 0x3354f000 + 15108
4   CoreMedia                       0x33552a3a 0x3354f000 + 14906
5   MediaToolbox                    0x31e1b50c 0x31e18000 + 13580
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x319cd92a 0x319a9000 + 149802

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x383c43cc
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3361b30d      r6: 0x001ada2c      r7: 0x2fffe97c
    r8: 0x2fffe968    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0000a0c0     r11: 0x334bd104
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffe97c      lr: 0x31a279a3      pc: 0x31a279ac
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x9fff +Logistics armv6  <c425fdbcb8fd0049193b8b9a907b6ab6> /var/mobile/Applications/E10C8ED3-1B10-4D06-A711-5562BAF2DE7A/Logistics.app/Logistics
   0x2f000 -    0x30fff  dns.so armv7  <35ac487c38e38ed5810d5ed0d5c67546> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe24fff  dyld armv7  <5db9f5d0275997de58efff111816706e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30028000 - 0x3004ffff  ContentIndex armv7  <67165d749b79ad4b14c8a24f14dab29d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x30050000 - 0x30054fff  ITSync armv7  <a0bf9af6f4ebc7e5977d3da853671162> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30149000 - 0x3016efff  AppSupport armv7  <ca2e9a4f0475af20028968840ab94ecf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30175000 - 0x3017ffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <36d71cd8dd49f5d5addb356f449b562a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30184000 - 0x30184fff  Accelerate armv7  <939f94df6c7e6e7a090ddee1ec09c844> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30185000 - 0x301b7fff  iCalendar armv7  <235e05f7e167e6dbbd75528a4a37f3a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x301b8000 - 0x301c3fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8faba7ded9b3527ccf54c2f224f9a12f> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x301c4000 - 0x301eefff  CoreText armv7  <821e9c7c935b6a8d735e2d2d9ebcee04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x301f6000 - 0x301fffff  IAP armv7  <36e57cf20df9fcea10ebd0d1c3526a9a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30247000 - 0x30279fff  MessageUI armv7  <51d0498fb3dba758dae660754f1afb9c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3027a000 - 0x3027efff  MobileMusicPlayer armv7  <f0e7d2d2d69e9cc2a84e20bced0e1d07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileMusicPlayer.framework/MobileMusicPlayer
0x302c6000 - 0x302cefff  CoreVideo armv7  <9259f5ae2a74b53e4f13b27fa3d511e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30348000 - 0x3034afff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <a0a25c381e45f8a3f4ec63bcb17a5a39> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x304a3000 - 0x304cefff  MIME armv7  <55a4de1d243273ee7ef4e86a85d591f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x304cf000 - 0x3050ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <c2b5985d8307d73b39140e76adfd2eb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3054a000 - 0x30569fff  Bom armv7  <37e498957087af50894156808e0a486b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30578000 - 0x30a4efff  WebCore armv7  <4e2bac4e01a15979c9ac096f78280db0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30a58000 - 0x30b12fff  Message armv7  <a5a7de97c57a6965f27547bf8ff8810c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x30b13000 - 0x30b13fff  vecLib armv7  <4eb91bf56603dc0db6784d8d3240bfa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30c1e000 - 0x30c23fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <91af9ee5b2f271cbd8c138b3c61e508d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30d05000 - 0x30d29fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <c57df668b510f025ee5a173ad30fb48e> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30d6c000 - 0x30decfff  QuartzCore armv7  <af0722911ffc74fc08075e9831a6222e> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30e5d000 - 0x30e72fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2b6a9404652dd2b5abd1c6a5583e8533> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30e73000 - 0x30ebdfff  GMM armv7  <72c87b3b08ab4359802b6efed472bf46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x30ec7000 - 0x30ed0fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <17ca8b5262cd6484d41efdc72c6fd057> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30ed1000 - 0x30f43fff  LDAP armv7  <a5f6d51ebcab28eeabe0f2bbbdeb8cc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LDAP.framework/LDAP
...
0x32aed000 - 0x32b07fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <0dc4e83b63c1350517949e24204817fb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32b09000 - 0x32b2dfff  Security armv7  <3a3406fe12445942f4d767c7fa4c24ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32b2e000 - 0x32b5bfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <08b68b92f987faff46a127f6f78708a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32b60000 - 0x33524fff  UIKit armv7  <47c9d61f9cbe72938d1bfb1588306b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3354f000 - 0x33580fff  CoreMedia armv7  <584770f5de9c599a2d420eb8666921ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33586000 - 0x33588fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <66057eb40ba62cb544fe00ac4f2b498e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x33594000 - 0x33599fff  MBX2D armv7  <ae091892e4419221d25f8db9307cedf0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3359a000 - 0x335d7fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1eb427066a911d979a024e445464a067> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x335d8000 - 0x33621fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <99401ed10ec4d5608ce23ec33dd757c6> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33627000 - 0x33632fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <03f3879bad1802636dadeb457ee74cb2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
```

only differnce i can see in this from the last is

```
14  Logistics                       0x00003904 -[RootViewController sendMessage:] (RootViewController.m:139)
```

so i then opened rootcontroller.m139 it is as below

```
[body appendFormat:@"\nDamage issue %d: %@\n", c, dr.comment];
```

here is a few lines from above and below m139 if its any help

```
  NSMutableString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Customer: %@\nComments:\n%@\n", 
                         self.nameEntry.text, self.commentsTextView.text];

[mailer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_appDelegate.appData.agentSignature, 0.7)
                 mimeType:@"image/jpeg"
                 fileName:@"signature.jpg"];
DamageReport *dr = nil;
NSUInteger c = 1;
for (dr in _appDelegate.appData.damageReports) {
    [body appendFormat:@"\nDamage issue %d: %@\n", c, dr.comment];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(dr.image, 0.7)
                     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"
                     fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"damage-%d.jpg", c]];
```

Comment: You'll neeed the file Logistics.app.dSYM to make this log look better. See : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html

Comment: where should i put this file should i use megaupload or something

Answer (score 3):

This crash log is not symbolicated. iPhone app Crash logs are useless without being symbolicated. This is because during a release build of an iPhone app, all the debug symbols are stripped from the binary and stored into a .dSYM (debug symbols) file.

In order to symbolicate a crash log, the .app file **AND** its corresponding .dSYM file need to be locatable on the computer (via spotlight). Once this is the case, the crash log can be dragged into Xcode's Organiser window into the Crash Reports section. Symbolication should happen during the import of the crash log.

If the .app and .dSYM files for this build were not saved, there is no way you can symbolicate this crash report and it will not help you.

Comment: so if i build and install a debug version to the phone then upload the crashlog here. i have the full xcode here

Comment: Yes, with a debug configuration, the debug symbols are not stripped, so any crash log will be fully symbolicated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check mailer with canSendEmail? Try to test application on device that has no configured email account.
Also make sure that dr.comment is not nil. The string can't be formatted with nil values.

Answer (score 0):

```
DamageReport *dr = nil;
NSUInteger c = 1;
for (dr in _appDelegate.appData.damageReports) {
    [body appendFormat:@"\nDamage issue %d: %@\n", c, dr.comment];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(dr.image, 0.7)
                     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"
                     fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"damage-%d.jpg", c]];
```

That looks very weird. What exactly is dr? If you set `dr` to `nil`, you neither can check the condition `in _appdDelegate…` or even access a property of it (`dr.comment`).

*I wanted to post that as a comment, but I cant?! Weird…*